# Virtualenv package installation without pip

Tags: python-2.7, debian, virtualenv

How should i install a package inside a venv using `sudo apt-get install`? If i use `sudo` then the package will be installed globally and not only inside the venv, if i don't use `sudo` i will have no permission to install it because i am not root and get some error like this:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How can i install a package if it is not included in pip? What is the solution?

Comment: `apt` does not know about virtual environments. You need to use `pip` instead.

Comment: And what if a package is not installable via `pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Virtualenv` is meant to create localized python environments. Thus, it can only control python software packages via `pip` (or `setuptools`, etc). `Apt` installs software for the entire system and is separate from `virtualenv`.

If you are looking to install software from `apt` without sudo, I'd suggest you compile the software yourself and install it to your local home directory. For most packages, this is relatively straightforward (There are some software packages that will not work well when installed into your home directory).

Google "apt-get without sudo" for more [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges).